# MySQL query to return rows between two date ranges

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table structure like this:

```
USER_ID START_DATE END_DATE   MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN  
======= ========== ========== === === === === === === ===
      1 2018-03-01 2018-03-15   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
      2 2018-02-20 2018-02-23   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
```

where the columns M/T/W etc. are either 1/0 to indicate whether the event occurs on a Monday/Tuesday/Wednesday etc.

So I need a query that i can run for a USER_ID between two dates which will return a row for each occurrence of an event for each day within that date range.

So, for example if a user has an event every Monday and Wednesday for the next four weeks, there will be one row with today as start_date and 4 weeks time as the end_date, with MON and WED set to '1'.

What I need is a query which in this case if I use a three week search period within that range would return 6 rows, each row with the date of the occurrence of the event.

I'm totally confused on how to approach this, any help appreciated!

Comment: show us what have you tried .  add  also a proper data sample and the expected  resul

Comment: give some data to analyse your query

Comment: This looks like really bad table design.  Why not just store event information for each day separately?  And if this is an assignment, then ask the instructor why he chose such a non standard design.

Comment: unfortunately this is a legacy system but from what i understand the reason for this design is to allow for recurrance, so the end date can actually be null, so that an event can be set to recur indefinitely, i.e. i can create an entry with a start date but no end date that recurrs every Monday and Wednesday, so the user can technically go to an event any time in the future. I will try to pull some sample data for it

Comment: Screen shot of some sample data - https://ibb.co/n2KAqH

Comment: Sample expected result - https://ibb.co/bJnzHx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go (assuming date ranges do not exceed 19 years each):

```
create table schedule(
  user_id int primary key not null,
  start_date date not null,
  end_date date not null,
  mon int not null,
  tue int not null,
  wed int not null,
  thu int not null,
  fri int not null,
  sat int not null,
  sun int not null
);

insert into schedule (user_id, start_date, end_date, 
                      mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun) 
  values (30, '2018-03-01', '2018-03-15', 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);

insert into schedule (user_id, start_date, end_date, 
                      mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun) 
  values (31, '2018-02-20', '2018-02-23', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0);
```

For **user_id = 30** (it's typed 8 times in the SQL):

```
select date_add(start_date, interval 7 * (d2.n * 100 + d1.n * 10 + d0.n) + weekday.d day) as day
  from 
    (select 1 as n union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 0) d2,
    (select 1 as n union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 0) d1,
    (select 1 as n union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 0) d0,
    (select 0 as d from schedule where user_id = 30 and mon = 1
     union select 1 as d from schedule where user_id = 30 and tue = 1
     union select 2 as d from schedule where user_id = 30 and wed = 1
     union select 3 as d from schedule where user_id = 30 and thu = 1
     union select 4 as d from schedule where user_id = 30 and fri = 1
     union select 5 as d from schedule where user_id = 30 and sat = 1
     union select 6 as d from schedule where user_id = 30 and sun = 1) as weekday,
    schedule s
    where user_id = 30
      and date_add(start_date, interval 7 * (d2.n * 100 + d1.n * 10 + d0.n) + weekday.d day) between s.start_date and s.end_date
  order by d2.n, d1.n, d0.n
```

Result:

```
day
==========
2018-03-02
2018-03-04
2018-03-09
2018-03-11
```

And for **user_id = 31** (it's typed 8 times in the SQL):

```
select date_add(start_date, interval 7 * (d2.n * 100 + d1.n * 10 + d0.n) + weekday.d day) as day
  from 
    (select 1 as n union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 0) d2,
    (select 1 as n union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 0) d1,
    (select 1 as n union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 0) d0,
    (select 0 as d from schedule where user_id = 31 and mon = 1
     union select 1 as d from schedule where user_id = 31 and tue = 1
     union select 2 as d from schedule where user_id = 31 and wed = 1
     union select 3 as d from schedule where user_id = 31 and thu = 1
     union select 4 as d from schedule where user_id = 31 and fri = 1
     union select 5 as d from schedule where user_id = 31 and sat = 1
     union select 6 as d from schedule where user_id = 31 and sun = 1) as weekday,
    schedule s
    where user_id = 31
      and date_add(start_date, interval 7 * (d2.n * 100 + d1.n * 10 + d0.n) + weekday.d day) between s.start_date and s.end_date
  order by d2.n, d1.n, d0.n
```

Result:

```
day
==========
2018-02-20
2018-02-21
2018-02-22
2018-02-23
```

Easy peasy.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I hope to try to implement this in the next day or two and then will mark as correct! lt looks on the right line anyway!